# How can I add a header card to a flutter card

Tags: flutter, material-design, flutter-layout

I am trying to add a header card which will be displayed on the upper-left edge of a flutter card, so far I haven't been able to achieve that. [This is an example of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpULM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Being new to flutter, I didn't know there was a Stack widget. The solution is to stack two cards wrapped in Positioned widgets.

```
class SummaryCard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          top: 40,
          height: 200,
          width: 350,
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.blue,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 20,
          top: 0,
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.green,
            elevation: 10.0,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap header card with Align Widget.

Here is a full code:

```
class Cards extends StatefulWidget {


@override
  _CardsState createState() => _CardsState();
}

class _CardsState extends State<Cards> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
      child: Card(
        elevation: 20,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: Container(
            width:100,
            height: 60,
            child: Card(
              elevation: 10,
              child: Text("header"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Containers are just for height and width control.

And here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Your solution adds the second card within the bounds of the parent card which isn't exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: so Can you be more precise ? so I can create the code for you

Comment: depending on my image, what do you want to be changed ?